# how to optimize DB query for table with millions of rows when info is sorted (sorted by date in this case)

Tags: database, postgresql, query, mongodb

Imagine you are chatting with your SO on Whatsapp and the conversation is years long, so there are thousands if not millions of messages.

```
CREATE INDEX date_index ON messages_table (date_column);
```

and then a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM messages_table
WHERE date_column > '2023-01-01' AND date_column < '2023-12-31'
ORDER BY date_column ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

Assuming the most common DB query is to get 50 messages with date greater than X and less than Y, I have some questions:

1. is this the best query?
2. how to design a table that can be optimized for this
3. is getting the 10 most recent messages efficient? how does the database actually implement this without having to read the entire table (and therefore a million records?)

My guess / my thoughts - if the index sorts the data on disk and LIMIT is used, then the machine can avoid reading all million+ records every time we want the "50 most recent messages", and similar queries like that?

Note, I haven't decided whether to use Postgres or MongoDB for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take a first run at optimization:

1. Update your index to:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX date_index ON messages_table (date_column DESC);
   ```

   WHERE DESC seems to be the desired (non-reversed) sort order for the column index.
2. Re-run your query with the prefixed `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`, and inspect the query plan, like so:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM messages_table
   WHERE date_column > '2023-01-01' AND date_column < '2023-12-31'
   ORDER BY date_column ASC
   LIMIT 50;
   ```

In the resulting query plan, you will find whether your query is capitalizing on the index.